# Solidity error with balances[] in constructor, "Index expression cannot be omitted"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

New to Solidity and smart contracts, been trying to setup a test environment on Windows but I'm stuck when trying to test run a truffle boxed environment (MetaCoin).

In the constructor below balances[] is doing something wrong. My IDE (vscode with solidity extension) throws a message: "Index expression cannot be omitted". Why is this showing up?

```
 contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor() public {
        balances[] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}
```

Also if I can somehow fix this, what's next? How do I make transfers between the accounts to see it in work?

I've been following this guide: https://medium.com/edgefund/ethereum-development-on-windows-part-1-da260f6a6c06

Comment: As you continue to learn about smart contracts, suggest looking at OpenZeppelin Contracts. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts
If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapping (address => uint) public balances;
```

balances is the mapping from address to uint but in your constructor you don't provide any address to set the uint to.

you can add `msg.sender` so it will set the initial balance to the address who deployed the contract.

```
balances[msg.sender] = 10000;
```

For the second question you can just call the `sendCoin` function